# Where are MOTD descriptions stored?

Tags: motd

I've created a custom MOTD (Message of the Day) and it works fine, but I noticed that it doesn't have a description in the Armbian Config utility (see screenshot). I checked the other MOTD files that come with the system which have a description, but they don't include the text shown for their descriptions.

I tried searching for `*motd*` files and even considered grepping one of the descriptions on the whole disk for a bit. I tried searching, but the only thing I can find about MOTD is how to make them at all, not how to provide descriptions for them.

**Where is the description text for messages-of-the-day stored?**

[image: MOTD descriptions in Armbian Config]

Answer (score 1):

I went ahead and just grepped the disk.

It seems that the descriptions aren't a standard part of MOTD, they're specifically hard-coded in the Armbian Config utility in `/usr/lib/armbian-config/functions.sh`

Comment: Try `/etc/motd` for the system motd.

Comment: @JeremyBoden, like I said, it's hard-coded in `functions.sh`. I found it, modified it, and now it's showing the description I wrote for the custom MOTD.